# If a finite set $G$ is closed under an associative product and both cancellation laws hold, then it is a group

Tags: group-theory

#### Problem

> Suppose a finite set $G$ is closed under an associative product and that both cancellation law hold in $G$. Prove that $G$ must be a group. Also show by an example that if one just assumed one of the cancellation laws holds, then the conclusion need not follow.

This is from *Topics in Algebra* by Herstein

#### Specific question

How can I prove the properties of group from the both cancellation laws? In short, the identity and invertibility. If $a$ and $b$ belong to $G$ then $ab$ belongs to $G$ (closure property), but does it imply that  it has an identity element.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? It's best if you indicate what you tried and where you ran into problems so that people can best determine how to help.

Comment: How can I prove the properties of group from the both cancellation laws. In short the identity and invertibility

Comment: Since $G$ is finite, for any $a \in G$, we have $\{ ab : b \in G \} = G$, so in particular there exists $e \in G$ with $ae = a$. Now prove that $xe = x$ for all $x \in G$.

Comment: If a and b belong to G then a.b belong to G. (closure property).but does it imply that  it has an identity element.

Comment: I just gave you  hint about how to do that. What do you not understand?

Comment: Hint: Cancellation is true if and only if, for all $a\in G$, $L_a:G\to G$ and $R_a:G\to G$, defined as $L_a(g)=ag$ and $R_a(g)=ga$, are $1-1$. A function from a finite set to itself is $1-1$ if and only if it is onto...

Comment: Hint for the second part: Take a set with at least two elements and define $x\cdot y = x$, for all $x,y$. You need to show it is associative, satisfies just one cancellation rule, and that it is not a group.

Comment: A minor quibble.  This is false; the empty set is not a group. I checked and this is Herstein's fault, at least in the edition I have.

Comment: @James Well spotted! I am surprised Herstein made that mistake, because it's a common pitfall.

Answer (score 7):

Hints:

> Cancellation is true if and only if, for all $a\in G$, $L_a:G\to G$ and $R_a:G\to G$, defined as $L_a(g)=ag$ and $R_a(g)=ga$, are $1-1$.

And:

> A function from a finite set to itself is $1-1$ if and only if it is onto...